# Access Form - Combo Box From Lookup Table, Updating Look Up Value Text to LookupID - No code telling it to

Tags: vba, ms-access

First time poster, long time Junior Varsity Access Developer

MS Access 2016 on Win 10 system (not connectable to public network)

I have form with a text field - Event Name (Pulled from existing value in Events table) and 3 unbound combo boxes (created from Wizard, select key field and lookup value text, hide key field, save value for later use) on a form that each pull values from a respective lookup table

Lookup table structure:

```
tblCategories: CategoryID (PK, Integer) | CategoryName (Text 255)
tblDirectorate: DirectorateID (PK, Integer) | DirectorateName (Text 255)
tblLocation: LocationID (PK, Integer) | LocationName (Text 255)
```

What should happen:

1. User completes the form, selects values from each of the combo boxes (Category, Directorate, Location) clicks Save Event button. (Tested - Values passed to SQL statement correspond to values from combo box)
2. Update SQL Statement runs, updates Events table and sets values in table to values on form (Update SQL Syntax correct, I did a debug.print to immediate window, copy and paste to QBE, run SQL, Update runs correctly)

What does happen:

1. User completes the form, selects values from each of the combo boxes (Category, Directorate, Location) clicks Save Event button. (Tested - Values passed to SQL statement correspond to values from combo box)
2. Update SQL Statement runs, updates Events table and sets values in table to values on form (Update SQL Syntax correct, I did a debug.print to immediate window, copy and paste to QBE, run SQL, Update runs correctly)
3. (Here's the part that I can't explain) The value of CategoryName in tblCategories updates to the value of CategoryID

   a. I do not have cascade updates on any of the tables

   b. Nowhere in ANY of the code in the entire DB is there a SQL statement to update tblCategories

   c. Nowhere in any part of the DB is there a command to update the value of CategoryName in tblCategories

   d. Neither the values of [tblDirectorate].[DirectorateName] nor [tblLocations].[LocationName] update to their corresponding ID field value.

I'm completely befuddled by this. I've deleted / recreated the combo box for the Category lookup, verified that the actions / properties for all 3 lookups are the same.

Has anyone previously experiences this, or can throw out some additional troubleshooting ideas?

Thanks!
Jordan

Comment: You are not use bound form with bound controls? Why not?

Comment: Something in the wizard? "...save value for later use."